# Should I save Client IP info in a database or cache or any alternative?

Tags: python, database, networking, ip

I'm programming an IM server in python. To be able to route messages to clients I will need the `client IP` and `Id` so I know who I am sending the messages to.

Should I save them into a SQL database or will accessing be too slow? Is there a better way of dealing with IP addresses in an IM server?

Comment: The IP is not suitable for IM routing. Chances are good that multiple users have the same IP due to NAT (corporate network, mobile internet, ...).

Comment: @ThiefMaster's point is the first of many issues which you'll encounter which have likely been resolved well elsewhere.  Do any of the existing open source implementations and/or specified protocols meet your needs?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have though about multiple users with the same IP. My thought was to give each client a unique id number so messages are sent to the client with the appropriate id even if sharing an IP.